# Handling XSD element declared twice

Tags: xsd

I have an XML Schema referencing two other schemas where the same element is declared twice resulting in an invalid schema.

Is there any built in XSD construct allowing me to handle this situation by ignoring one occurrence or is this situation just fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fundamentally wrong - a schema is specifically intended to make things clear and unique. You need to address that somehow - XSD has no way of ignoring something that's in the schema - anything in the schema file must be valid.